# SharePoint 2010 and 2007 compatibility

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

One of my clients has migrated all its teamsites from SP 2007 to SP 2010. They kept most of the sites in 2007 compatibility view though. One of the sites that I customized 2 years ago is not working properly. The javascript code has error and they cannot edit most of the webparts content.

I tried to troubleshoot the site in my farm. However, I face more issues because the teamsite I created is not in 2007 compatibility view. (Ribbon, ajax, etc.)

**Is there a way to create a site in 2007 compatibility view from scratch?**

Comment: Have you tried just setting the master page to the 2007 master page via SharePoint designer?

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: Well, this site uses customized master pages and page layouts. Changing it to the default creates runtime errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't, unless you want to spend A LOT of time and effort, which is better spent debugging.

Is the new farm running in a different domain?

Comment: Yes. It is in a different network, and don't have access to it. Looks like the best option is to try to port the site to SP 2010